# how to add current class selected div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

### Codepen **[Demo](http://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/GqJZoe)**

here i used hover function on `jquery`.  it works correctly. but i need selected `li` on hover div.

```
$('.block-templates-container:not(:first-child)').hide();
   $(".block-name").each(function() {
      $(this).hover(function() {    
         $('.block-templates-container').hide();
         var getId = $(this).attr('id');
         $('.block-templates-container#' + getId + '_show').show();    
      });    
    });
```

when i hover rightside block(**heading design,content design**) the `li` not selected. how to fix this?

Comment: I believe the li is also selecting would you be more specific with your questions please

Comment: i don't know why you make this so complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding class on hover

```
  //Sidebar 
  $('.block-templates-container:not(:first-child)').hide();
      $(this).hover(function() {
          $('.block-templates-container').hide();
          var getId = $(this).attr('id');
          $('.block-templates-container#' + getId + '_show').show();

          $('.block-name').not(this).removeClass('current');
          $(this).addClass('current');
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You don't need to use `.each()` and then put hover. also need not to use class selector withid, you can use id selector directly (id must be unique through out the DOM) - see below code

```
$(".block-name").hover(function() {
    $('.block-templates-container').hide();
    var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + getId + '_show').show();
});
```